# Can I download security patches of Ubuntu 22 and Ubuntu 20 on one server

Tags: 22.04, security

I have a requirement to download security patches for Ubuntu 22 and 20 including minor versions of them in one server. Is there any way to achieve this by setting some option.

Comment: It's unclear if you want the *patches* or the *patched packages*. It's also unclear if you are trying to set up a proxy, a mirror, or to apply the security updates to a single system...of if you perhaps just want to try your hand at patching. Please edit your question to make the question clear.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming updates...*

***Some lead on the way forward:***

`$ man apt-get` and then use `/` to search, as in...
`/-t,` - to find the --target-release option
`/-d,` - to find the --download-only option
`/-s,` for --simulate, may help you get things right before actually doing it...

Using apt-get with these options you should be able to do what you ask for.